# How can I configure Juju for deployment on HP Cloud?

Tags: juju, openstack, hp-cloud

HP Cloud has a new cloud service out based on Open Stack. How can I configure my environments.yaml to connect to the new service?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have `juju-quickstart` installed, you can do `juju quickstart -i`; this will give you a form to fill out for your cloud provider.

Here are the full instructions:

- [Setting up Juju with HP Cloud](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-hpcloud.html)

Official docs:

- [HP Cloud for Juju documentation](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-hpcloud.html)
- [Documentation](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/provider-configuration-openstack.html#openstack-configuration)
- General OpenStack configuration: [How can I configure Juju for deployment on OpenStack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132411/how-can-i-configure-juju-for-deployment-on-openstack)

Comment: Make sure you're not using `ppa:juju/devel`. The public-bucket on HP Cloud doesn't have images that correspond to the version of juju the ppa provides. So you can't even bootstrap an instance. It took me quite awhile to figure out what was going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You will also need to set your access-key and secret-key information as an environment variable or in the environments.yaml file.

Adding to your environments.yaml file should make it look like this:

```
environments:
  hpcloud:
    juju-origin: ppa
    control-bucket: juju-hpc-az1-cb
    admin-secret: [any-unique-string-shared-among-admins-u-like]
    default-image-id: [8419]
    region: az-1.region-a.geo-1
    project-name: [your@hpcloud.com-tenant-name]
    default-instance-type: standard.small
    auth-url: https://region-a.geo-1.identity.hpcloudsvc.com:35357/v2.0/
    auth-mode: keypair
    type: openstack
    default-series: precise
    authorized-keys: [CONTENTS (not path) to your ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub key]
    access-key: [PUT YOUR ACCESS-KEY HERE] 
    secret-key: [PUT YOUR SECRET-KEY HERE]'
```

You can find the access-key and secret-key by logging into your HP cloud control panel and displaying your API keys.