# How can I configure Juju for deployment on OpenStack?

Tags: juju, openstack

I would like to test juju charms on trystack.org, however I have not found any docu, how to configure juju for the openstack API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off you need juju and charm-tools, ensure you have the latest stable juju:

```
sudo apt install juju-core
```

Then you need to provide your OpenStack credentials files to Juju, assuming it's named `credentials.yaml`:

```
juju add-cloud <cloud name> <cloud definition file>
```

#### References:

- [Official Docs](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started-general)

Comment: Thanks Jorge.. but I have not found a way to configure environments.yaml work with trystack.org yet

Comment: @txwikinger Trystack doesn't expose any Storage, only compute. You need both Swift and Compute to use Juju.