# How do I configure Juju for deployment on Rackspace Cloud?

Tags: juju, openstack

I'd like to use Juju to deploy to Rackspace Cloud, how can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

> This doesn't work and is really an inprogress placeholder while we figure out how to make it work, this answer is useless.

First off you need juju and charm-tools, ensure you have [backports enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25717/how-do-i-enable-the-backports-repository) (they are enabled by default) to get the latest Juju:

```
sudo apt-get install juju-core charm-tools
```

Do a `juju generate-config -w` to generate a config for OpenStack that you can customize for your needs.

Here's an example for Rackspace Cloud Servers to orchestrate services.

- The file is in `~/.juju/environments.yaml`
- Items in brackets above [] should be changed to your own info.
- Get your tenant-name  from: https://mycloud.rackspace.com as shown on the screen below.

[image]

[image]

Official docs:

- [Documentation](http://jujucharms.com/docs/provider-configuration-openstack.html)
- General OpenStack configuration: [How can I configure Juju for deployment on OpenStack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132411/how-can-i-configure-juju-for-deployment-on-openstack)

Comment: I told rackspace I want them to work on that. Feel free to vote: http://feedback.rackspace.com/forums/71021-product-feedback/suggestions/4997037-document-connecting-juju-to-rackspace-cloud-

Comment: I'm trying to use juju and Rackspace Openstack solution, and I cannot authenticate myself. As this question was open more than a year ago, is there any new guide or tutorial regarding this issue? And, is it working? Because Jorge said that this was not working at the time of posting the question. Any news on this regard?

Comment: We still do not support Rackspace at this time.

Comment: I'm guessing it's still not supported on Rackspace? We have a project starting and am looking at various deployment strategies, but servers have already been provisioned on Rackspace.

Comment: @Andre You can use the manual provider with Rackspace, that's the only workaround we have right now: https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-manual.html

Comment: Ah thx @JorgeCastro, this will help :)

Comment: Hi this is old question.I need to know Rackspace supported now ??@JorgeCastro

Comment: @Sajith4U No, not yet, sorry!

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCastro you said this thread is useless.we can't deploy juju in Rackspace.