# Can anyone manage to correctly configure environments.yaml with a Rackspace cloud?

Tags: configuration, juju

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure Juju for deployment on Rackspace Cloud?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166102/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-deployment-on-rackspace-cloud)

I have already read all official documentary, blog posts and have talked to rackspace support but there is nothing clear on that topic.

My `environments.yaml` file looks like this:

```
environments:
 default:
    type: openstack
    provider: rackspace
    rackspace_username: infinidad
    rackspace_api_key: ******************************
    control-bucket: juju-****************************
    admin-secret: ***********************************
    default-series: precise
    ssl-hostname-verification: true
```

And when I `juju bootstrap`, the terminal says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/juju", line 8, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/control/__init__.py", line 183, in main
    env_config.load_or_write_sample()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/environment/config.py", line 229, in load_or_write_sample
    self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/environment/config.py", line 115, in load
    self.parse(file.read(), path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/environment/config.py", line 138, in parse
    config = SCHEMA.coerce(config, [])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/lib/schema.py", line 266, in coerce
    new_dict[k] = self.schema[k].coerce(v, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/lib/schema.py", line 233, in coerce
    new_subvalue = self.value_schema.coerce(subvalue, value_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/lib/schema.py", line 301, in coerce
    return self.schemas[selected].coerce(value, path)
KeyError: 'openstack'
```

It's quite frustrating.

Can anyone manage to correctly configure that file with a Rackspace cloud?

Comment: Sorry to dupe this but this still doesn't work, we've got some things to fix with Rackspace in order to make this happen, please click the star to subscribe to the question and when it works I'll make sure to update it, thanks!