# juju doesn't bootstrap due to "ERROR command failed: no tools available" error

Tags: juju, cloud, openstack

I've seen other posts (e.g. [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132411/how-can-i-configure-juju-for-deployment-on-openstack)), but I'm still struggling to install juju on my openstack cluster.

I have swift working, but juju doesn't seem to want to bootstrap. I created the bucket (I tried without the bucket existing and had the same problem):

```
zestrada@cloud1:~$ swift list
juju-44c885823005ec6033e09c81f99980a6

zestrada@cloud1:~$ juju bootstrap -e openstack -v
2013/04/24 01:46:36 INFO environs/openstack: opening environment "openstack"
2013/04/24 01:46:36 INFO environs/openstack: bootstrapping environment "openstack"
2013/04/24 01:46:46 INFO environs: reading tools with major version 1
2013/04/24 01:46:46 INFO environs: falling back to public bucket
2013/04/24 01:46:46 ERROR command failed: no tools available
error: no tools available
```

I've tried with and without the `-e openstack` switch, yielding identical results. Trying with [juju-origin: ppa](https://juju.ubuntu.com/get-started/openstack/) resulted in `ERROR command failed: juju-origin: expected nothing, got "ppa"`

I also tried manually specifying the `auth-url` - but again, no change.

Here are the relevant parts of my environments.yaml:

```
zestrada@cloud1:~$ grep -A25 openstack: .juju/environments.yaml  | grep -vP "\s+#"
  openstack:
    type: openstack
    admin-secret: SECRET
    control-bucket: juju-44c885823005ec6033e09c81f99980a6
    default-image-id: "119295c7-2afc-4eda-bd64-2f8bef894b0d"
    default-instance-type: "1.small"
    auth-mode: userpass
```

My environment variables are correct since I can access all installed services (nova, swift, cinder, glance, keystone) with no trouble.

Comment: This is an issue with the tools not updated in the public bucket. The team is working on a fix, I'll leave a comment when that's done.

Comment: I see, thanks for the update and explanation! I'm still new to juju, so I have no idea what the infrastructure is like.

Comment: Try it now and let me know if it works!

Comment: Same story - do I need to update anything on my end? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I don't think you need to update anything, I'll keep investigating.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here. [How can I copy Juju tools for use in my deployment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285395/how-can-i-copy-juju-tools-for-use-in-my-deployment)

nutshell use $ juju sync-tools to copy from a globally available release to your private cloud.

Comment: I see, but is seems like this requires a bootstrap: I get `error: environment has no access-key or secret-key` Or is there something missing in my environments.yaml? Thanks!

Comment: I am getting ERROR gomaasapi: got error back from server: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR  when I try and run juju sync-tools

Answer (score 1):

If your juju version is 1.10.0 then I think you just ran in to what I did; which in turn I believe is explained by the following:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1172973

Basically, when juju attempts to access the public bucket (where the charms are downloaded for local storage) it uses credentials stored within code. These hard-coded credentials do not include an access-key or secret-key. But before a connection is made, there is an assertion which requires these credentials - thus the sync-tools attempt is failing (and I'm guessing this is what is causing the ERROR after it falls back to the public bucket on bootstrap).

Comment: Hmmm this seems plausible, how can I get the credentials? I'm getting this: `error: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`

Comment: I took a guess and used the credentials from my Amazon Web Services account (this is where the public bucket is hosted). However, I should warn that I haven't found any official documentation that stated this is required/recommended. If you want to try this you can head over to http://aws.amazon.com and sign-up (it won't cost you anything but time). Then go to My Account / Console -> Security Credentials. Under the Access Keys tab is your Access Key ID and click show to see your Secret Access Key.
Though, I had more success when I built juju-core myself: https://github.com/prabhakhar/juju-core

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm against some tight deadlines on another project right now, but it definitely sounds like it's worth a shot - so I'll give it a go next week!