# How can I copy Juju tools for use in my deployment?

Tags: juju

When I try to boostrap my cloud environment I receive the following error:

```
ERROR command failed: no tools available
error: no tools available
```

How do I make these tools available for my environment?

Answer (score 3):

For juju-core you can retrieve tools from the public release via the sync-tools subcommand.

```
 $ juju sync-tools

fwiw, the full help for the command (2013/4/26)

 $ juju sync-tools -h

 usage: juju sync-tools [options]
purpose: copy tools from the official bucket into a local environment

options:
--all  (= false)
    copy all versions, not just the latest
--dev  (= false)
    consider development versions as well as released ones
--dry-run  (= false)
    don't copy, just print what would be copied
-e, --environment (= "")
    juju environment to operate in
--public  (= false)
    write to the public-bucket of the account, instead of the bucket private to the environment.
```

This copies the Juju tools tarball from the official bucket into
your environment. This is generally done when you want Juju to be able
to run without having to access Amazon. Sometimes this is because the
environment does not have public access, and sometimes you just want
to avoid having to access data outside of the local cloud.

Comment: Might be worth noting that in order to actually copy the tools from the public AWS bucket you need working AWS credentials set in the environment until https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1172973 is fixed.

Comment: ...and just a note for the people reading the above comment, that bug is now marked as "fix released".

Comment: This is now deprecated in juju 2.0