# What is needed for the authorized-keys in the environments.yaml file?

Tags: juju, hp-cloud

I am trying to get Juju working in HPCloud; however, I can't figure out what is needed for the authorized-keys in the environment.yml file.

I already read this post [How can I configure Juju for deployment on HP Cloud?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116174/how-can-i-configure-juju-for-deployment-on-hp-cloud) and tried creating a public key from the private key from HPCloud management console. In addition, I tried creating the a public key and putting that information inside of the environment.yml file, but the status command is stating "server refused to accept connection."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be the exact output of your ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, here's mine as an example:

```
type: openstack
default-series: precise
authorized-keys: |
  ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCuzAhXssdiPaxQ9mEXd6VnRcqhkrJMgt0kQi8FmQgNbO0hKaGfEcdTYbCaA4V37iWwIXSosfkSZ4oglZvbz9dBs6zRC/sObVXGr5DCq58UY7W1LgEF+nSprAGZZs+lJTqs+KNnB8cnJ3Drs2peTNOnlCmCw4zbuAO2ftNuWzaVJRpX5IJae/lxr0B9fbtlQtEcWREUeJRHNi5koQO583TEg0ViyFV6MK+o3SM1FKeXxXaQ/94vJx8Of/CbUnBOyXOUG0p8FK3gyhlsbdsEdRXzYzQ5L1lES+44oujlMHN/+vVw0OMmeMGpnMx2NeFp/tN6y7nvoFjx+Wduzaiwl2RX jorge@lowgirl
```

Make note of the |, I think you need it.

Comment: hmm.. I tried your suggestion; however, if I don't quote the string the parser has a problem parsing the file and if I quote the suggested output I have the same problem as I initially had.